# Mongo Observe when a document date field is past

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, meteor, observer-pattern

I'm using MongoDB with MeteorJS, and I want to know if it's possible to observe a field value ?
I know we can observe a doc update, creation, or removing but I don't know about field value.

Each of my document have a field named `time_next_action` (with a Javascript Date value) and I want update each document when this attribute is past.

Actually I have a interval called 2 times/second, but :

- It require a `Collection.find({})` each time
- The callback isn't exactly called at the right time, but 0 to 500ms  after.

This is my actual code (but I don't like that)

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
 beginIntervals();
}, 500);

let beginIntervals = function() {
  let now = new Date()
  let games = Games.find({time_next_action: {'$lt': now}}).fetch()

  _.each(games, game => {
    /* Do something */
    Games.update(game._id, {'$set': update})
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package to define a *reactive* time variable then wrap your update in a `Tracker.autorun`:

```
let now = Chronos.currentTime();

Tracker.autorun(function(){
  let games = Games.find({ time_next_action: { $lt: now }}).fetch();
  _.each(games, game => {
  /* Do something */
    Games.update(game._id, {'$set': update})
  })
});
```

*However* the effect is basically the same as your code, just a bit more concise. Chronos will update the reactive time every second (changeable) and that will cause the tracker to fire which will run a find and then do your updates.

Comment: Yeah, it's the same things. But with your code I'll make request all the time no ? (like every 0.01sec)

Comment: No, just every second or whatever interval you pass to chronos. Ex: `Chronos.currentTime(2000)` would update every other second.